# Call onDateSet on a Fragment activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have problems getting information of the DatePickerFragment on my Fragment activity.
I have this code, extracted from the Google developer page:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    ADD add = new ADD();
    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) add.getTargetFragment(), year, month, day);
}}
```

And here is my MainActivity, when I receive the date selected by the user:

```
public  class ADD extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
//code
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    Log.w("DatePicker", "Date = " + year);
    mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(dayOfMonth).append("-")
                    .append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-")
                    .append(year).append(" "));
}}
```

I appologize if this question have been asked before. I've been actively searching in this page and this question has beed answerd only for Activities, not for Fragments. Also, I have to note that I'm not a Java expert. My intuition tells me that the problem may be in the 'return' of the DatePickerFragment, but I'm incapable of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to trigger `setTargetFragment` method inside your `ADD` fragment:

```
DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
datePickerFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 1234);
datePickerFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "DatePickerFragment TAG");
```

In addition replace `onCreateDialog` method with:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getTargetFragment(), year, month, day);
```